# Reconstructing Control Flow of Decompiled Program

Tags: c++, bytecode, control-flow, decompiler

I am writing a very simple decompiler (in C++) for a basic compiled bytecode (an entirely different language). The executor uses a stack-based machine, and most instructions are fairly easy to piece back together.

I have run into an interesting predicament with conditions and looping constructs. One of the opcodes in the bytecode sets the location of the executor (sort of like a jmp instruction) if the previous operand evaluates to false. Thus, if the condition is met, the executor will continue execution at the current instruction pointer.

For now, I've implemented these as simple gotos, but I'd like to expand this functionality to piece together the original if / else constructs. Here's an example of the original source:

```js
function myFunction() {
  if (this.var1 == "foo") {
    this.var2 = "bar";
  } else {
    this.var2 = "baz";
  }
}
```

And my decompiled output:

```js
goto label23;

function myFunction() {
    if (!(this.var1 == "foo")) {
        goto label16;
    }
    this.var2 = "bar";
    goto label21;
    label16:
        this.var2 = "baz";
    label21:
        return 0;
}
label23:
```

Is there a method that I can apply to this "decompiled" source to piece the conditions back together in a way such that it resembles the original source? I know no decompiler is perfect, but I'm curious how decompilers like Ghidra tackle this sort of problem. Because my bytecode is not necessarily machine code (and more like compressed source code), I assume my use-case is much simpler than Ghidra's decompiler.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should clarify my question. The decompiler is created in C++, but the bytecode I am "decompiling" is for another, proprietary language that I've learned the opcodes for through reverse engineering.

Comment: FYI, you can only use `this->` when the function is a member of a class.  You should be able to reference class methods and members without indirection or using `this`.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding my usecase. The decompiled code is not C++; it is another entirely different language. Members are accessed with '.' in this language. I have posted no valid C++ code in this post, but I am moreso looking for strategies in C++ to achieve this task (hence the tagging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reko](https://github.com/uxmal/reko) is a decompiler that tries to reconstruct C-like code from machine code. It has a pass that reconstructs high-level constructs like `if`, `while` and `switch` statements. The code is based on the paper "Native x86 Decompilation using Semantics-Preserving Structural Analysis and Iterative Control-Flow Structuring" by Edward J. Schwartz, JongHyup Lee, Maverick Woo and David Brumley.

Although it is written in C#, it shouldn't be terribly hard to port the one class to C++.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for! Would you kindly point me to the relevant file?

Comment: https://github.com/uxmal/reko/blob/master/src/Decompiler/Structure/StructureAnalysis.cs is the class. Do feel free to reach out to me if you have questions about the code.